# Order Item details in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am new to woocommerce and would like know the sql query to get the order item details for a particular order id.

like, item name, qunatity, price, line tax, line total, discount(if any).

Thanks
Aj

Comment: Googling `woocommerce sql get order by id` seems to get useful results

Comment: i have tried that, but almost all of them return order details but not the order item details

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce provides a great set APIs for almost all the purpose, If you prefer non sql method, here is how you can achieve this by using WC APIs

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
/* get_items() retrives all the line items belong to that order
 * you can also examine get_items() function for the actuall sql query used.
 */
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

    $product_id   = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $item['product_id'] );
    $quantity     = (int) $item['qty'];
    $variation_id = (int) $item['variation_id'];
    $variations   = array();
    $cart_item_data = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_again_cart_item_data', array(), $item, $order );

    // using $product_id you can anything related to that product ( line item product )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sark for the reply.
But, im looking for the SQL query for the smae.